# Deploying custom page into the pages library using a feature in SharePoint 2007?

Tags: 2007, development, feature

I have a custom page and want deploy it into the pages library of the site using a feature in SharePoint 2007. Whenever the activated the page should added into the pages library and should removed on the feature deactivation event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to read up on the Module element of a Feature to do this.

http://blogit.create.pt/blogs/andrevala/archive/2009/01/10/SharePoint-2007-Deployment_3A00_-Module-Features.aspx

I should also add that you will need a Feature Receiver if you want to  remove the file from the library upon Feature Deactivation. [Here's how](http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/removing-provisioned-files-from-sharepoint-during-feature-deactivation/).